# What should I do when latest Redactor WYSIWYG-Editor dosen't compatible with vimperator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, firefox-addon, redactor, vimperator

I'm learning Ruby on Rails recently. And using Redactor JS as my WYSIWYG-Editor tool by installing [redactor-rails](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) (`gem 'redactor-rails'` in Gemfile ).

However, I found the latest Redactor.js **DOSE NOT** compatible with vimperator!!!

Details as below:

- I input some text in Editor:
  [image: InDiv]
- And click **< />** button:
  [image: inTextarea]

Everyting is GONE!? I think, that might because of nothing saved in `real textarea` by trigging the `</>` button

---

However, I've tried **[Redactor.js 8.8.2](https://github.com/html5cat/redactor-js), everything works!**

Here my investigation:

- **[8.8.2](https://github.com/html5cat/redactor-js) Can compatible, redactor works fine!**
- [9.1.4](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) Doesn't compatible
- [9.1.5](https://github.com/aeberhard/redactor) Doesn't compatible
- [9.1.8](https://github.com/yiiext/imperavi-redactor-widget) Doesn't compatible

I want to use the latest version, beacuse of beautifully **real html** code.

What should I do or fix this bug? Thanks in advance!!

### Version Information

- Firefox: 25.0.1
- Vimperator: 3.8.1
- Redactorjs: 9.1.4/9.1.5/9.1.8 (cannot work) | 8.8.2 (works)

### Video

You can check the video at: http://content.screencast.com/users/Marslo.Jiao/folders/Media/media/55ff1193-29fe-4edf-9691-7555cc33933e/redactor_vimperator.wmv?downloadOnly=true

Comment: [File a bug](http://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/list)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stackoverflow is not the vimperator issue tracker.

Comment: So, you means it's not the problem for Redactor? But the Redactor 8.8.2 works fine for vimperator. I think that might be something wrong with Redactor configure.